# Ansible Inventory file --extra-vars in a yaml file for multiple hosts

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

Here below is a inventory file that I need to use when I run my playbook with.

```
[eu-de_eos]
eos-apps-45180 ansible_host=10.20.0.21
eos-apps-45181 ansible_host=10.20.0.22

[eu-de_ora]
ora-apps-45184 ansible_host=10.20.0.23
ora-apps-45185 ansible_host=10.20.0.24

[all_servers:children]
eu-de_eos
eu-de_ora
```

---

This is my playbook which only does a cat /etc/hosts for every host from inventory having a role with a task for this purpose.

```yaml
- name: Cat /etc/hosts  
  hosts: "{{ variable_host | default('all') }}" 
  remote_user: "{{ variable_user | default('ansible') }}" 
  roles: 
      - cat-hosts
```

---

To be able to connect via ssh to remote hosts from the inventory, I need to go through a bastion.

I know that when working with a bastion I need to add **ansible_ssh_common_args** like **eu-de_ora:vars** or  **eu-de_eos:vars**. More details [here](https://www.middlewareinventory.com/blog/ansible-bastion-ssh/). I need to mention that the connection through a bastion works, but I need to use **vars** **in a different file, that's the main requirement** like below:

This is a yaml file that I use but this is only for eu-de_ora and the 10.20.30.40 should be the IP of the bastion.

```
ansible_port: 22
ansible_user: linux
ansible_ssh_private_key_file: ~/.ssh/ora.pem
ansible_ssh_common_args: "-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ProxyCommand=\"ssh -q ansible@10.20.30.40 -o Port=65222 -W %h:%p\""
```

To run my playbook using the above YAML file as `--extra-vars` I run the command as :

```bash
ansible-playbook -i inventory/inventory-otc-50160  manage_users.yml --extra-vars "@inventory/oravars.yaml" --extra-vars "variable_host=eu-de_ora"
```

But this scenario is only for eu_de-ora. I need to run my playbook for both remote hosts and having **ansible_ssh_common_args** in a different file. I expect to have a different yaml file that I can use for both remote hosts. I need to mention that I tried different ways but none of them worked.

```
#This is not working :(
eu-de_ora:
  ansible_port: 22
  ansible_user: linux
  ansible_ssh_private_key_file: ~/.ssh/ora.pem
  ansible_ssh_common_args: "-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ProxyCommand=\"ssh -q ansible@10.20.30.40 -o Port=65222 -W %h:%p\""

eu-de_eos:
  ansible_port: 22
  ansible_user: linux
  ansible_ssh_private_key_file: ~/.ssh/eos.pem
  ansible_ssh_common_args: "-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ProxyCommand=\"ssh -q ansible@30.40.50.60 -o Port=65222 -W %h:%p\""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need extra vars, just a correctly crafted inventory:

Example file structure:

```
.
├── demo_playbook.yml
└── inventories
    └── demo
        ├── group_vars
        │   ├── all.yml
        │   ├── eu-de_eos.yml
        │   └── eu-de_ora.yml
        └── hosts
```

`hosts` file:

```ini
[eu-de_eos]
eos-apps-45180 ansible_host=10.20.0.21
eos-apps-45181 ansible_host=10.20.0.22

[eu-de_ora]
ora-apps-45184 ansible_host=10.20.0.23
ora-apps-45185 ansible_host=10.20.0.24

[all_servers:children]
eu-de_eos
eu-de_ora
```

Group variables:

- `all.yml`

```yaml
---
ansible_port: 22
ansible_user: linux
ansible_ssh_common_args: "-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ProxyCommand=\"ssh -q ansible@{{ jump_host }} -o Port=65222 -W %h:%p\""
```

- `eu-de_eos.yml`

````yaml
---
ansible_ssh_private_key_file: ~/.ssh/eos.pem
jump_host: 30.40.50.60

* `eu-de_ora.yml`
```yaml
---
ansible_ssh_private_key_file: ~/.ssh/ora.pem
jump_host: 10.20.30.40
````

Using the above inventory with the dummy `demo_playbook.yml`:

```yaml
---
- hosts: all_servers
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg:
          - "I'm running on {{ inventory_hostname }}"
          - "I'd connect to target with user {{ ansible_user }}"
          - "I'd use ssh port {{ ansible_port }}"
          - "The private key for ssh would be {{ ansible_ssh_private_key_file }}"
          - "The ssh option I would use are: {{ ansible_ssh_common_args }}"
```

gives:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inventories/demo/ demo_playbook.yml 
[WARNING]: Invalid characters were found in group names but not replaced, use -vvvv to see details

PLAY [all_servers] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [ansible.builtin.debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [eos-apps-45180] => {
    "msg": [
        "I'm running on eos-apps-45180",
        "I'd connect to target with user linux",
        "I'd use ssh port 22",
        "The private key for ssh would be ~/.ssh/eos.pem",
        "The ssh option I would use are: -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ProxyCommand=\"ssh -q ansible@30.40.50.60 -o Port=65222 -W %h:%p\""
    ]
}
ok: [eos-apps-45181] => {
    "msg": [
        "I'm running on eos-apps-45181",
        "I'd connect to target with user linux",
        "I'd use ssh port 22",
        "The private key for ssh would be ~/.ssh/eos.pem",
        "The ssh option I would use are: -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ProxyCommand=\"ssh -q ansible@30.40.50.60 -o Port=65222 -W %h:%p\""
    ]
}
ok: [ora-apps-45184] => {
    "msg": [
        "I'm running on ora-apps-45184",
        "I'd connect to target with user linux",
        "I'd use ssh port 22",
        "The private key for ssh would be ~/.ssh/ora.pem",
        "The ssh option I would use are: -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ProxyCommand=\"ssh -q ansible@10.20.30.40 -o Port=65222 -W %h:%p\""
    ]
}
ok: [ora-apps-45185] => {
    "msg": [
        "I'm running on ora-apps-45185",
        "I'd connect to target with user linux",
        "I'd use ssh port 22",
        "The private key for ssh would be ~/.ssh/ora.pem",
        "The ssh option I would use are: -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ProxyCommand=\"ssh -q ansible@10.20.30.40 -o Port=65222 -W %h:%p\""
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
eos-apps-45180             : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
eos-apps-45181             : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
ora-apps-45184             : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
ora-apps-45185             : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

*Note the warning about invalid group names where you should replace dashes (`-`) with underscores (`_`).*